# PDF metadata editor for iOS

Tags: ipad, pdf, books, metadata

I have several PDF ebooks in my iBooks.
[image]

Some of them have their titles & authors visible. Some only displayed as "untitled".

Is there any PDF metadata editor for iPad?

Comment: have you tried:
1. synch pdf books with iTunes on you mac
2. http://www.sybrex.com/products/macgui/infomanager/ on your mac 
3. sync back with iTunes

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of [PDF Pen on the Mac](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/) and would encourage you to shoot them an email linking back to here. Adding that as a feature to their new [iOS PDF editor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdfpen/id490774625?mt=8) might be something they can do quickly and really make it quicker to make these sorts of changes.